# Does using proxy on class fire all the methods on that class

Tags: javascript, proxy

I'm using a third party library to handle some behavior for me. Instead of adding console.log to each method that calls the library I would like to use the `Proxy` primitive to intercept all the uses and print them out for me. Code looks like this

```
import lib from 'lib'

const instanceOfLib = new lib(id)

const handler = {
  get(target, propKey, receiver) {
      console.log('pp', 'GET1', target, propKey, receiver);
      const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
      if (typeof targetValue === 'function') {
        return function (...args) {
            console.log('pp', 'CALL', propKey, args);
            return targetValue.apply(this, args); // (A)
        }
      } else {
        console.log('pp', 'GET2', target, propKey, receiver);
        return targetValue;
      }
    },
}

const proxied = new Proxy(instanceOfLib, handler)
return proxied
```

this returned `proxied` is what my code would use to trigger methods on the library class. The issue I'm having is that the library instance has a destroy function that blocks usage of its api after the destroy method was called. When I go to use a function off the proxied instance it errors out that I can't use its api after it has been destroyed.

Does passing the library instance to `Proxy` fire all of its methods? Is there anyway around that if it does?

Comment: Not sure if I fully got your problem, but why don't you add a condition in this line `if (typeof targetValue === 'function')`? I guess you can check if `instanceOfLib` is in destroyed state?

Comment: From what I've read, all method calls come in as `get` to the proxy, so you need to trigger the call from the proxy to keep the behavior consistent with what a regular class behaves as.

Comment: Yes, that's done with this line `return targetValue.apply(this, args);`, if I got your problem, the solution is to conditionnally execute this line

Comment: I created a repl to test this out somewhere else, https://repl.it/repls/NervousSilkyDebugger.. It works as expected, I'm going to look further into the library I'm using. Thanks